# Android, send and receive XML via HTTP POST method

Tags: android, xml, http, http-post

There is a relevant question, but I could not get the answer clearly.

I would like to POST a short xml code

```
<aaaLogin inName="admin" inPassword="admin123"/>
```

to a specific URL address over HTTP. The Web service will send me back a XML code. The important part is that I will parse the received XML, and I want to store that as a file.

```java
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header  
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.192.131/"); //URL address

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity("<aaaLogin inName=\"admin\" inPassword=\"admin123\"/>",HTTP.UTF_8); //XML as a string
    se.setContentType("text/xml"); //declare it as XML
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
    httppost.setEntity(se);

    BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient .execute(httppost);
    tvData.setText(httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString()); //text view is expected to print the response
```

there is something wrong with receiving the response. Besides, I did not write anything to save the received XML as a file. Can someone write a code snippet?

Answer (score 14):

Ok, I have figured out soon after I posted this question.
This code here works fine:

```java
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.192.131/");

try {
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "<aaaLogin inName=\"admin\" inPassword=\"admin123\"/>", HTTP.UTF_8);
    se.setContentType("text/xml");
    httppost.setEntity(se);

    HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
    tvData.setText(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));        
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the content of the response using:

```
String responseXml = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

You can then write this to a file using something [like this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

> there is something wrong with receiving the response

Since you havn't said *what* is wrong with receiving the response it's somewhat difficult to help you with this point.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Spring RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-android/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) in [Spring for Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/)?