# Android and PHP load website

Tags: php, android, amazon-s3

i want to open [amazon login](https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_clouddrive_us&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fclouddrive%2F%3F_encoding%3DUTF8%26action%3Dsign-out%26associationHandle%3Damzn_clouddrive_us%26pageId%3Dclouddrive_authportal_us%26path%3D%252Fclouddrive%252F%26ref_%3Dpd_irl_gw_r%26signIn%3D1%26useAuthPortal%3Dtrue%26useRedirectOnSuccess%3D1&pageId=clouddrive_authportal_us) in webview android. but i wanted this login automatically done with the help of code. As i am the android developer don't have much idea about PHP.

please tell me the way i can automatically submit this form in php.
how to $_POST in php ?

Comment: Now its a good time to start ... all you need is curl

Comment: will start :-) but any quick solution for above problem ?

Comment: @ExtremeProgrammer deleted my answer, it's not to the point

Comment: Ok any solution for above problem ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5871311/464552 they use GET but you can change that to POST

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7532730/1226894 ..a typical to login to amazon using CURL & PHP