# Restful api with CURL in android

Tags: android, curl

I am making a app that requires login auth. And i have api:

```
curl --user username:password -X GET -http://sample.com
```

Now i want to auth the login and get the response.

I have look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870611/curl-in-android) but am not getting any result.

I have done this. But it keep going on the catch block.

```
public static String getRequest() {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();

        URI uri = new URI("http://sample.com");
        httpGet.setURI(uri);
        httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"),
                HTTP.UTF_8, false));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));

        String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (readLine != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(readLine);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
            readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

How can i accomplish this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: put `e.printStackTrace();` in catch block and post the exception here. Did you add the Permission for internet ?

Comment: Print catch log will easy to find out the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call network operation on main thread. This case crash. Use volley library or use your code in AsyncTask or thread. Remember to update your ui in main thread.

Comment: i tried with asynctask but not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910575/how-to-get-access-token-paypal-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). That'll simplify life for you.