# cURL requests (-d) for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, curl

I have been trying to look for cURL requests for Android Studio, specifically for this type of request in particular:

```
curl -d "grant_type=client&client_id=123&client_secret=456" https://api.someapp.com/v2/oauth2/token
```

I have been looking for solutions around the site, but the only closest answer to exist is:
[CURL in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870611/curl-in-android/5871311)

This doesn't solve my issue of the **-d** command (the link solves for **-u**), as well as the need for customizable headers (link gives only :, rather than &).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, never mind guys!

POST with data:

```
try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String postURL = "https://api.someapp.com/v2/oauth2/token";
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type","client"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id","123"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret","456"));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
            post.setEntity(ent);
            HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
            if (resEntity != null) {
                // Successful results
                Log.i("Results", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```