# Http Post not working in Android

Tags: android, http-post

I am working with an android application which is having XML data as Web service.
My task is to add data by posting the values using HTTP Post and retreiving the data and showing in list view. While post I need to encrypt it as UTF-8 format.

Below I gave my code.

```
private String postSyncXML() {
    String url = strMainUrl + strSubUrl;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs
            .add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", strUniqueId));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("first_name", strFirstName));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("last_name", strLastName));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", strEmail));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", strPhone));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notes", strNotes));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("is_sms", strIsSms));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("is_email", strIsEmail));


    UrlEncodedFormEntity form;
    try {
        form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8");
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
Log.d("", "Add Guest URL "+url);
        httppost.setEntity(form);

        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        String resp = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        Log.i("Method call", "postSyncXML srv response:" + resp);
        return resp;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **not working** then whats happening actually? Throwing any exception, if yes then logcat output.

Comment: Yes, It show error, I call the above method while in button click. Because When I click the button all data which I pass here it needs to post in web, then i can see the newly added data on website .But now the website is not showing the newly updated data.

Comment: ERROR is postSyncXML srv response:<Checkin><Error>error</Error></Checkin>

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.192.131/");

try {
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "<aaaLogin inName=\"admin\" inPassword=\"admin123\"/>", HTTP.UTF_8);
    se.setContentType("text/xml");
    httppost.setEntity(se);

    HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = httpresponse.getEntity();
    tvData.setText(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[Android, send and receive XML via HTTP POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013373/android-send-and-receive-xml-via-http-post-method)