# android XML send and get receive via HTTP post

Tags: android, xml, api, xmlhttprequest, http-post

first I'm trying to be able to send a HttpResponse with parameters such as:

http://www.syslang.com/frengly/controller?action=translateREST&src=en&dest=iw&text=good&email=YYY&password=XXX

the code looks something like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.syslang.com/frengly/controller");   
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("src", "en")); 
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dest", "iw"));  
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "good"));                  
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "YYY")); 
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "XXX"));
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs,HTTP.UTF_8);  
httpPost.setEntity(entity);  
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
```

the [API structure is available at http://www.frengly.com/ (under the API tab)](http://www.frengly.com/) and has a total of 5 parameters (src, dest, text, email, password).

so far every time I tried to call

> HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
>   I keep getting an IO Exception :(

After that I should get something like this structure:

```
-<root>
  <text>good</text>
  <translation>טוב</translation>
  <translationFramed>טוב|</translationFramed>
  <missing/>
  <existing>good,</existing>
  <stat>1/1</stat>
</root>
```

I think I'll handle this part to build XML and parse it as I need

p.s: I checked 
[Android, send and receive XML via HTTP POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013373/android-send-and-receive-xml-via-http-post-method)
and many other links, which didn't help me a lot.

let me know if any code lines from my application needed...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to POST.
You need to GET instead.

```
// Construct your request here.
String requestURL= "http://www.syslang.com/frengly/controller?action=translateREST&src=en&dest=iw&text=good&email=YYY&password=XXX"

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(requestURL);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

And also internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
....
....
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response, but this still isn't working. the same IO Exception is raised on the line "HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);" line :(

Comment: Did you add the Internet permission?

Comment: oh maybe I didn't :( , any chance you guide me through this, I am pretty noob in android dev

Comment: thanks a lot mate, how simply how useful I sure you saved me a lot of trouble... thanks again :)